# How to securely lock Ubuntu, when fragile program is installing?

Tags: 14.04

I managed to install game that has to go through lots of updates. It's not a game for Ubuntu, more for Windows or Mac. As I see the speed of it's own update, I don't think it'll finish before I will have to go to sleep. I would leave it over night, but I would like to have it updating.

This program is extremely fragile. You will run it twice = Crash; You will click on it when it's busy = Crash. It's like severly fragile program that needs superiously special treatment to hold it up, so it does it's job and I can finally run it.

Is there a way to lock screen and keep it going? I mean, sleeping is not a solution, it will probably crash. I mean I could [Super] + [L], but this will result in sleeping over 30 minutes. Is there something to do about this?

**Is there a way, to securely block computer from people who should stand away from it, while keeping program going on until I'm back?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pressing [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[L] instead of [Super]+[L]. This will lock your screen without sleeping or hibernate.

Comment: And this will stay forever working? If I connect laptop to charger, are you entirely sure it will not fall asleep within next 24h?

Comment: At least my laptop won't. I'm quite lazy and sometimes I don't shutdown it. I just lock it and go to bed. Next morning I just unlock it and everything is normal.